# Extract current cell address

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract the current cell in VBA without passing it in parameter of the function.

I mean, for example, if the formula is in cell B35, I want to extract the address (line = 35, column = 2), in the VBA code of the formula.

I thought the active cell would do it, but no, it extracts the address of the cell where the cursor is.

Do you know how I could do it?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: The active cell *is* the cell where the cursor is. Per definition.

Comment: Share the code you use and excample where you need the cell address.

Comment: How do you define 'the current cell' if it's not the active one where the cursor is? If it's a range variable in your code (in this example I'll call it 'currentcell') then you could use `currentcell.address` to get the full address or `currentcell.row` and `currentcell.column` to get the row and column numbers individually.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. @Spencer Barnes, the current cell is the cell where the formula is called. If it is called in cell B35, I want the adress line = 35, column = 2

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `Application.Caller` which is the object that calls VBA. It can be used inside a function to return the cell calling the UDF, not the `ActiveCell`

[Application.Caller property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller)

An easy example would be this:

```
Public Function ThisCell() As String


ThisCell = "ROW:" & Application.Caller.Row & " - COLUMN:" & Application.Caller.Column

End Function
```

If you type now in any cell `=ThisCell()` it will return its row and column:

[image]

Notice the output is different in all of them, even if they use the same UDF with no arguments.

Comment: There is also a built in ThisCell function.

Comment: My bad, function name should be a different one

Answer (score 1):

A similar one to Foxfire And Burns And Burns' answer, but no vba needed.

Apply this formula, then copy it and paste as values.

`="line = "&ROW()& " column= "&COLUMN()`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below codes

```
Sub ExAddress()
    MsgBox "Row: " & ActiveCell.Row & vbNewLine & _
            "Column: " & ActiveCell.Column
End Sub
```

[image]